# Usage of "likely" in a sentence

Tags: word-usage

How to use the word likely in a sentence which conveys the same meaning as below.

> It is probable that you will be the next president.

Is the above sentence correct? If yes what is the similar sentence using likely. If it is not, correct that sentence too.

Comment: *Likely* does not mean "possible"; it means "probable".

Comment: What kind of homework question is this?

Comment: @J.R. Difficult, obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence is grammatical.

You can use the adjective likely in the same way as you have used the adjective probable in your sentence as follows:

It's likely that you will be the next president.

Answer (score 1):

Your original sentence is grammatically correct, but it sounds very unnatural; I don't think you'd see a sentence like that unless it was in an essay. The more natural way to phrase this sentence, using 'likely', would be:

"You will likely be the next president."

or you could instead use 'probably':

"You will probably be the next president."